# What does middle-click on the taskbar do?

Tags: unity, taskbar

I know it's supposed to lower the current window, but it has very unexpected behaviour when used on the taskbar. Once one makes the connection that it lowers a maximized window, it sort of becomes logical. But before knowing that that was the purpose, to me it seemed like it randomly switched focus.
Maybe some explanation is in order for new users...